# Otel agent host metrics monitoring jenkins using grafana

Tags: jenkins, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, otel

I have tried following https://plugins.jenkins.io/opentelemetry-agent-metrics/ document to set up server monitoring in jenkins and display through grafana.

But facing below issue when triggering pipeline job

From jenkins pipeline we have triggered **onMonit(debug: true)**  under stages.

Error:

```
[on-monit] Looking for node_exporter implementation... 
[on-monit]   Delegated exec node_exporter (fixed order delegation to other process factories) Could not find node_exporter: IOException: Cannot run program "node_exporter": error=2, No such file or directory Check if node_exporter is installed and in PATH 
[on-monit]   Exec node_exporter (uploaded node_exporter from master to remote machine) FATAL: IOException while writing node_exporter executable java.io.IOException: Is a directory 
[on-monit] * Exec node_exporter (uploaded node_exporter from master to remote machine) 
[on-monit]     java.lang.RuntimeException: could not start node_exporter

[on-monit] Looking for otel-contrib implementation... 
[on-monit]   Delegated exec otelcol-contrib (fixed order delegation to other process factories) Could not find otelcol-contrib: IOException: Cannot run program "otelcol-contrib": error=2, No such file or directory Check if otelcol-contrib is installed and in PATH 
[on-monit]   Exec otelcol-contrib (uploaded otelcol-contrib from master to remote machine) FATAL: IOException while writing otelcol-contrib executable java.io.IOException: Is a directory 
[on-monit] * Exec otelcol-contrib (uploaded otelcol-contrib from master to remote machine)
[on-monit]     java.lang.RuntimeException: could not start otelcol-contrib
Could not start node_exporter + otel-contrib processes
```

under both jenkins master server and agent server installed as below

```
~/opentelemetry-agent-metrics$ ls node_exporter-1.5.0.linux-amd64/
 LICENSE  **node_exporter**  NOTICE 


~/opentelemetry-agent-metrics$ ls otelcol-contrib_0.70.0_linux_amd64/ 
LICENSE  **otelcol-contrib** README.md
```